# Erro While Fetching SQL data

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

so i was just extracting data from my database and i encountered following error.
The code goes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/haider")
df = pd.read_sql_table("ahmed", engine)
```

while running this code i got following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [46], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_sql_table("ahmed", engine)

File E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:286, in read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    282     raise ValueError(f"Table {table_name} not found")
    284 # error: Item "SQLiteDatabase" of "Union[SQLDatabase, SQLiteDatabase]"
    285 # has no attribute "read_table"
--> 286 table = pandas_sql.read_table(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
    287     table_name,
    288     index_col=index_col,
    289     coerce_float=coerce_float,
    290     parse_dates=parse_dates,
    291     columns=columns,
    292     chunksize=chunksize,
    293 )
    295 if table is not None:
    296     return table

File E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1460, in SQLDatabase.read_table(self, table_name, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, columns, schema, chunksize)
   1417 """
   1418 Read SQL database table into a DataFrame.
   1419 
   (...)
   1457 
   1458 """
   1459 table = SQLTable(table_name, self, index=index_col, schema=schema)
-> 1460 return table.read(
   1461     coerce_float=coerce_float,
   1462     parse_dates=parse_dates,
   1463     columns=columns,
   1464     chunksize=chunksize,
   1465 )

File E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1003, in SQLTable.read(self, coerce_float, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
   1001 else:
   1002     sql_select = select(self.table)
-> 1003 result = self.pd_sql.execute(sql_select)
   1004 column_names = result.keys()
   1006 if chunksize is not None:

File E:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1405, in SQLDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1403 def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1404     """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
-> 1405     return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

NOTE: My database doesn't have any password and secondly i was already installed PyMySQL too.

i tried to explain an error that i got while fetching sql data using python and i expect to get a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to try the following

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/haider").connect()
```

I think you might be missing the connect() part at the end.

Comment: it woked but now data is not being shown like it is only showing name of the columns while data is not being displayed